# Searching an array of objects in MongoDB using the C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Following the advice of [this article](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index-use) I created a blob index on an array of objects in my documents. For example:

```
{
...
    "itemID" : 37,
    "MetaData" : [ 
        {
            "FileExtension" : "TXT"
        }, 
        {
            "EmailSubject" : "GAS DESK HEAD MEETING"
        }, 
        {
            "DocumentType" : "EMAIL"
        }, 
        {
            "Date_BestEmailSent" : ISODate("2001-01-26T04:11:32.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "Date_ParentDate_BestDate" : ISODate("2001-01-26T04:11:32.000Z")
        }, 
        ...
        ],
    ...
}
```

I'm now parsing a search tree in C# to build a query using the MongoDB C# driver:

```
IMongoQuery expression; 
switch (leaf.Op)
{
    case SearchOperation.Equals:
        expression = Query.EQ(leaf.Field, leaf.Value);
        break;
    case SearchOperation.Contains:
        expression = Query.Matches(leaf.Field, leaf.Field);
        break;
    ...
}

if (_rootLevelFields.Contains(leaf.Field))
{
    return expression;
}
return Query.ElemMatch("MetaData", expression);
```

In this case, if my search criteria was `FileExtension EQ 'TXT'` It would run:

```
db.test.find({"MetaData": {$elemMatch: {"FileExtension":"TXT"}}})
```

This runs very slowly and the explain indicates it's scanning all records and not using my Index. If I manually run:

```
db.test.find({"MetaData": {"FileExtension":"TXT"}})
```

It uses the index and runs much faster. In this case it appears I don't want to use ElemMatch but the MongoDB Builder namespace doesn't seem to accommodate this type of query e.g.

```
Query.EQ("MetaData", expression);
```

is not syntactically correct. I've poured over the documentation and even the MongoDB driver source code but can't find how to do what I want. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EQ` method accepts only `BSONValue` as a parameter, but you're trying to pass a `IMongoQuery` instance.

In your second query you're basically searching this document in `MetaData` array :

```
{"FileExtension":"TXT"}
```

You will need to create a new BsonDocument and pass it  into your `EQ` method:

```
Query.EQ("MetaData", new BsonDocument(leaf.Field, leaf.Value));
```

You can check the [documentation for EQ method](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/c4f8b961-cb0f-156e-a75b-45f05565f78b.htm) for more details.